# passing null to bind parameters in Groovy

Tags: sql, groovy

i am trying to write a small groovy script, that reads data from an csv file, evaluates the data and writes the data into a SQL DB.

Some of the read data from the csv line can be empty - in that case the insert should pass NULL to the database. For performance and security reasons i build a single sqlQuery before the eachWithIndex iteration and fill the params inside the iteration.

```
    def sqlQuery="""INSERT INTO database (
                    [Id],
                    [document],
                    [extension], 
                    [token]
                    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NULL)"""

jobList.eachWithIndex{ it, i ->
      eIDenter = it[0]
      eDoc = it[1] 
      eExt = it[2]
      sqlParams = [eID, eDoc, eExt]
      ...
}
```

While i can simply pass NULL values to columns in the iteration, that are always empty (because they don't exist in the csv file) i am not sure how that works for bind parameters in groovy. 
The variable "eExt" can be filled or be null if the data does not exist in the csv file.

How can i make sure that the bind parameter explicit delivers NULL to the database when it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Elvis`-operator:

```
jobList.eachWithIndex{ it, i ->
   ....   
   eExt = it[2] ?: 'NULL'
   // or
   eExt = it[2] ?: null
   ....
}
```

Comment: When i assign the Value 'NULL' to eExt the Word NULL is put into the database as a literal / varchar. When i assign null to eExt the variable inside the groovy script is null and the column is ignored when the sql statement is executed. This means that not a real NULL value is put inside the database - the column remains empty.

Comment: what do you mean by `empty`? it's either a `null` or not-nullable exception

Comment: i think it is best explained by a SELECT over the database once the Script is finished: SELECT * FROM database where extension IS NULL -> returns 0 rows. SELECT * FROM database where extension = 'NULL' -> returns 200 rows, so does SELECT * FROM database where extension = '' (2 single quotation marks) - that means depending on which line with elvis operator i use the column is either "NULL" as a varchar or "empty" (''). The column [token], that i pass NULL directly in the VALUE section (not via bind parameter) is NULL and is selectable (SELECT * FROM database WHERE token IS NULL)

Comment: what SQL API are you using? `groovy.sql` or something else?

Comment: the SQL API is a proprietary class/object of the used DMS (d.velop/d.3)

Comment: the line that executes the insert is :   d3.sql.execute( sqlQuery, sqlParams);  .  (i think it is based on groovy.sql)

Comment: that's what I thought. Maybe there's some proprietary constant to use for NULL values there, something like `insert into a (col1) values([NULL])`. Maybe you would have to create the `sqlQuery` with all params yourself and use the `d3.sql.execute( sqlQuery )` method